# Set maxDate based on minDate in ngxdaterangepicker angular 8

Tags: angular, bootstrap-daterangepicker, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I am trying to set maxDate value based on minDate value selected. The idea is that you can select any day in the past as minDate, but the maxDate must be equal to minDate plus 15 days.

I have this in my html

````
```<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd formControlName="pick_dates"
                class="form-control" placeholder="{{'list.select' | translate}}"
                [minDate]='minDate'
                [maxDate]='maxDate' [timePicker]="true" [locale] = "locale"/>```
````

Is there any way to get the minDate value selected before sending the pick_dates form?

What I wish would be something like:
 have this in my html

````
```<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd formControlName="pick_dates"
 class="form-control" placeholder="{{'list.select' | translate}}"
            [minDate]='minDate'
            [maxDate]='minDate'+15 days
            [timePicker]="true" [locale] = "locale"/>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To set maxDate based on minDate 'ngxDaterangepickerMd ' provides one
> more attribute 'dateLimit'. So if you set 'dateLimit' say 5 then
> whatever you choose on datepicker it will automatically disable all
> dates after 5 days from chosen date. Plus if you want that limit not
> to allow selection beyond current date then set 'maxDate' attribute to
> currentDate in component.ts file as 'maxDate = moment()'.

```
<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd formControlName="pick_dates"
       class="form-control" placeholder="{{'list.select' | translate}}"                
       [dateLimit]="dateLimit" [maxDate]='maxDate' [timePicker]="true"
       [locale] = "locale"/>
```

component.ts:

```
maxDate = moment();
dateLimit = "5";
```

Comment: maxDate is not working with `"ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^6.0.4"`

Answer (score 4):

```js
startDateClicked($event) {
    this.maxDate = moment($event.startDate._d).add(1, 'month');
  }
  endDateClicked($event) {
    this.minDate = moment($event.endDate._d).subtract(1, 'month');
  }
```

```html
 <input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd [(ngModel)]="selected" [showCustomRangeLabel]="true"
                  [ranges]="ranges" [showCancel]="true" [keepCalendarOpeningWithRange]="keepCalendarOpeningWithRange"
                  [showRangeLabelOnInput]="showRangeLabelOnInput" opens="right" [timePicker]="true"
                  [locale]="{format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'}" (datesUpdated)="applyFilter()" [minDate]="minDate"
                  [maxDate]='maxDate' (startDateChanged)="startDateClicked($event)"
                  (endDateChanged)="endDateClicked($event)">
```

Comment: this works good!! However, when I clicked "Clear" it has still the restricted dates. Any idea to reset the dates without refresh the page?

Comment: Use the below code to clear the dates.

//Declaration
@ViewChild(DaterangepickerDirective, { static: true })
    daterangepicker: DaterangepickerDirective;

//Method

 clear(): void {
        this.daterangepicker.clear();
    }
//Enable the clear button as below
showClearButton=true

Comment: If my answer works for you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting it right, what you can do is add a (change) event there and when you change the date you can recalculate the min date and the maxdate Example =>

```
<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd formControlName="pick_dates"
  class="form-control" placeholder="{{'list.select' | translate}}"
  [minDate]='minDate' (change)="updateTime($event)"
  [maxDate]='maxDate' [timePicker]="true" [locale] = "locale"/>
```

Assuming that you are using moment().
On the .ts file =>

```
updateTime(e){
 this.minDate = moment(e);
 this.maxDate = moment(e).add(15,'days');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, what I need is that the maxDate value will update based on the first value selected. For example, you can select any day in the past (example: 2020-05-15), and with this value, the maxDate allowed would be 2020-05-30). If you pick another date, for example 2020-05-28, the maxDate allowed would be 2020-06-12 and so on.

Comment: Then what you need to do is just change the maxDate and not the minDate, depending on the actual date selected wich is the $event in this case.

Comment: according to the docs it you should past the $event -> https://fetrarij.github.io/ngx-daterangepicker-material/simple